# Hive - computed columns in where clause

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, where-clause

Im running a hive query which looks like below.

```sql
SELECT from_utc_timestamp(arrival_date, "IST") AS `Date`
    FROM table_name
    WHERE 1 BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00'
            AND '2018-12-02 00:00:00';
```

Here 1 refers my first select column(converted to IST timezone). But it didn't return any rows.

Sample data on arrival_date column:

```sql
select arrival_date from table_name;

2019-01-01 21:34:12
2019-01-04 06:12:46
```

Then I tried this,

```sql
SELECT from_utc_timestamp(arrival_date, "IST") AS `Date`
FROM table_name
WHERE from_utc_timestamp(arrival_date, "IST") 
BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00'
            AND '2018-12-02 00:00:00';
```

Now Im getting the data.

But in where clause again Im converting the data, this may lead to performance issues on terabyte size tables.

How can I use the computed column in where clause?

Answer (score 1):

It the table date is in UTC and parameters in IST then you can convert parameters to UTC:

```
SELECT from_utc_timestamp(arrival_date, "IST") AS `Date`
    FROM table_name 
 WHERE arrival_date BETWEEN to_utc_timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00', "IST")
                        AND to_utc_timestamp('2018-12-02 00:00:00', "IST");
```

The best way would be to calculate parameters separately if possible and pass dates already in UTC. For example using shell and call hive script with parameters.

For example do in the shell:

```
date_start_IST="2018-12-01 00:00:00"
date_end_IST="2018-12-02 00:00:00"

date_start_UTC=$( export TZ='GMT' && date -d 'TZ="Asia/Kolkata" '"$date_start_IST" +"%F %H:%M:%S" )
date_end_UTC=$( export TZ='GMT' && date -d 'TZ="Asia/Kolkata" '"$date_end_IST" +"%F %H:%M:%S" )

echo "$date_start_UTC, $date_end_UTC"
# prints 2018-11-30 18:30:00, 2018-12-01 18:30:00 

#call Hive script:

hive -hiveconf date_start_UTC="$date_start_UTC" -hiveconf date_end_UTC="$date_end_UTC" -f your_script.hql
```

In the script your_script.hql:

```
SELECT from_utc_timestamp(arrival_date, "IST") AS `Date`
        FROM table_name 
     WHERE arrival_date BETWEEN '${hivecong:date_start_UTC}'
                            AND '${hivecong:date_end_UTC}';
```

**In such way partition pruning will work (if the table is partitioned by arrival_date)** because no function is applied to predicate and optimizer can derive partitions even before execution.

**If it is not partitioned, and the file is ORC, predicate push-down will work.**

**If it is not partitioned and not ORC, then it will be full scan**, does not matter will it be functions in predicates and columns or not.

Answer (score 0):

one approach can be subquery

```
select * from (SELECT from_utc_timestamp(arrival_date, "IST") AS `Date`
FROM table_name
) a where a.Date BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00'
            AND '2018-12-02 00:00:00';
```